# Accumulation Points of a Complex Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, complex-numbers

Let $z$ be a complex number of absolute value 1: $ z=e^{i\theta},  0 \le \theta \lt 2\pi$.  What are the accumulation points of the sequence $\lbrace z^n \rbrace$?  Distinguish between the case where $\theta$ is a rational multiple of $2\pi$ and the case when it is not.  Be sure to justify all of your assertions.

So far I have the following:

By DeMoivre's theorem, $z_n=\cos n\theta + i\sin n\theta$.
Also, $|z|=1$, so $z_n$ is on the unit circle for all $n$, and any value of $\theta$.  I suppose the thing that is tripping me up is the part about$\theta$ being a rational multiple of $2\pi$.  Is this the case when $\theta = 2\pi p/q$? If so, what difference does it make?

Comment: You mean $z^n$, not $z_n$.

Comment: If $\theta = p/q$ is a rational number, think about the value of $z^q$.

Comment: Yes, I did mean $z^n$, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1) The subgroup $\theta\mathbb{Z}+2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $\frac{\theta}{2\pi}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.

If $\theta>0$, this can actually be refined as $\theta\mathbb{N}-2\pi\mathbb{N}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $\frac{\theta}{2\pi}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.

In this case, use it to show that every point on the unit circle is an accumulation point of the sequence $(z^n)$.

2) If $\frac{\theta}{2\pi}\in\mathbb{Q}$, say $\theta=\frac{2\pi p}{q}$ with $p,q$ integers such that $0\leq p<q$, given your assumptions. what are the values taken by $z^n$ when $n$ ranges over the positive integers? The sequence is periodic of period $q$. So there are finitely many values. All are $q$ roots of unity. If you arranged to have $p$ and $q$ relatively prime, the sequence hits all the $q$ roots of unity over each period.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $z=e^{i\theta}$, where $\theta = \frac{3}{10}2\pi$ $= \left(\frac{3}{10}\cdot\text{whole circle}\right)$.  Then the powers of $z$ are at points corresponding to the following multiples of the circle:
$$
\frac{3}{10},\quad \frac{6}{10},\quad \frac{9}{10},\quad \frac{12}{10}\equiv\frac{2}{10},\quad \frac{5}{10},\quad \frac{8}{10},\quad \frac{11}{10}\equiv\frac{1}{10},\quad\frac{4}{10},\quad \frac{7}{10},\quad\frac{10}{10}\equiv 0,
$$ 
and then it starts over again.  We've got three times around the whole circle and returned to the starting point in 10 steps.  That's what happens when you have a rational multiple of the whole circle, and that's why it happens.

The main thing to know to understand what happens when what you have is *not* a rational multiple of the circle is that what you see above doesn't happen.  Suppose it did: suppose for example that you return to the starting point on the 43rd step after going six times around the circle.  Then you must have had $\left(\theta=\frac{6}{43}\cdot\text{whole circle}\right)$  What would happen if that didn't?

**Later note:** If $\theta$ is *not* a rational multiple of $2\pi$, then one never hits the same point twice.  That implies that one hits *infinitely* many points on the circle.  So you have a set of infinitely many points in a bounded interval.  One can prove that every set of infinitely many points in a bounded interval must have an accumulation point.  However, in this case, one wants to show that *every* point is an accumulation point.

[to be continued . . . . . ]

Comment: So if $\theta$ is a rational multiple of $2\pi$, then $z^n$ has no accumulation points, as we can find a neighborhood of $z_n$ which doesn't contain an element other than $z_n$.  If $\theta$ is not a rational multiple of $2\pi$, then every point on the unit circle becomes an accumulation point. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.  There is a bit more to do.  How one knows that it's really _every_ point is something that one could explain, and in some contexts should explain.  Possibly I'll add something explicit about that......

Comment: I can see how to construct an argument that $z^n$ will have no accumulation points if $\theta$ is a rational mutiple of $2\pi$, but it's not quite clear how to discuss $\theta$ not a rational multiple of $2\pi$.  What should I be thinking about here?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, and $z = e^{2\pi i \theta}$. We are interested in studying the behavior of the sequence $z^n$.

The case $\theta \in \mathbb{Q}$ has been widely discussed here, so let us assume $\theta \notin \mathbb{Q}$. In that case if $m$ and $n$ are distinct natural numbers, then $z^m \neq z^n$ (why?).

Now fix $N$, and consider $1,z,z^2, \ldots,z^N$. They are $N+1$ distinct points in the circle, say $z^k = e^{2\pi i \theta_k}$, so there must be $0 \leq m < n \leq N$ such that $|\theta_m - \theta_n| < 1/N$ (why?). Let $w = z^{m-n}$. What can you say about the sequence $w^k$?

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: I know there must exist a convergent subsequence, which implies that $|\theta_m-\theta_n|\lt\epsilon$ for $m,n\ge N$ sufficiently large, but I don't know why that should be true less than $N$.  I also can't see how to show this would generalize to any arbitrary $\theta$.

Comment: I guess I am asking how to show that $z^n$ is distributed evenly around the unit circle.

Comment: We need to prove that, for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \epsilon > 0$, there exists $n$ such that $|\alpha - \theta_n| < \epsilon$. 

Now if $1/N < \epsilon$ and if we can show that $w = z^{m-n}$ is a rotation by an angle less than $\frac{2\pi}{N}$ , then for some $k$, $\theta_{k(m-n)}$ will satisfy the said inequality.